# Scroll Google Play Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, google-play

I am trying to extract all the ID's for apps when searching the google play store. By default it loads 50 apps but if you scroll down it loads more apps. Is there a ways I can get it to load the entire page etc?

Below code works for extracting the first 50:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=insurance&c=apps")
html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

IDtags=soup('a')
l=list()
for ID in IDtags:
    x=ID.get('href',None)
    if x.find("/store/apps/details?id=")!=-1:
       if not(x[23:] in l):
            l.append(x[23:])
            print(*l, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can receive it in one call, as it is a different page.
However, maybe this may help:

To receive these results (second page), you need to pass **next page token**, that could be found in a HTML script node. This is how script node looks like in **first page HTML**:

[image]

And the next page token looks like this:[image: Next page token]

In the payload for the second page, next page token is located at the end of it:

[image]

Note, that second page in this example is being retrieved with **HTTP post method**

In case to check, if you are parsing a correct next page token and all the results you need, you can verify it by calling an API called SearchApi. Here's a link of Google Play Store [documentation](https://www.searchapi.io/docs/google-play-store).